# SQL Scalar Valued Function Return Null

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008, t-sql, null

**Problem:**

I have a Scalar Valued Function returning data as VARCHAR(MAX) or NULL (function below), I am using this function to explode a long text string and grab single values (of multiple data types).

I am now trying to insert this data into another table but converted to proper data types but it's failing if the returned value is null.

The field I'm trying to populate is `DATETIME NULL` so if the function returns null I want to just select null, otherwise I want to convert the `VARCHAR` to a `DATETIME`, so far I have:

```
(SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, dbo.UDEF_GetFromTextString('Date=', ',', RawData))) AS LineDate,
```

What I can't do is both handle the null value and convert to a `DATETIME`, can someone give me a line function to do this (if possible without calling the function twice)?

**Error:**

```
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Procedure UDEF_DC_TRANSLATE_CALL_DATA, Line 11
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
```

**UDEF_GetFromTextString FUNCTION**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UDEF_GetFromTextString]
-- Input start and end and return value.
   (@uniqueprefix VARCHAR(100),
    @commonsuffix VARCHAR(100),
    @datastring VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) -- Picked Value.
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @ADJLEN INT = LEN(@uniqueprefix)

    SET @datastring = @datastring + @commonsuffix


   RETURN ( 
    CASE WHEN (CHARINDEX(@uniqueprefix,@datastring) > 0) 
         AND (CHARINDEX(@uniqueprefix + @commonsuffix,@datastring) = 0)
    THEN SUBSTRING(@datastring, PATINDEX('%' + @uniqueprefix + '%',@datastring)+@ADJLEN, CHARINDEX(@commonsuffix,@datastring,PATINDEX('%' + @uniqueprefix + '%',@datastring))- PATINDEX('%' + @uniqueprefix + '%',@datastring)-@ADJLEN) ELSE NULL END
    )
END
```

**Edit:**

After the very useful help from AakashM, I have located the line and value causing the error, it was trying to pass dd-mm-yyyy as mm-dd-yyyy, working until a value for the day was over 12.

To resolve it I just changed:

```
(SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, UDEF_GetFromTextString('Date=', ',', RawData))) AS CallDate
```

To:

```
(SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, UDEF_GetFromTextString('Date=', ',', RawData), 105)) AS CallDate
```

Comment: "it's failing if the returned value is null" - what's the error message?

Comment: Added error to question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

This isn't complaining about not being able to convert `NULL` from `varchar` to `datetime`. This is complaining about converting and ending up with a date outside the range of `datetime`. Proof:

A sample function that returns either a date-like string, or `NULL`:

```
create function Fexample (@i int) RETURNS varchar(max) 
as
begin
return case 
when @i = 5 then '2012-05-16' 
when @i = 2 then '1750-01-01'
else null end
end
go
```

Some values to pass to this function:

```
declare @a table ( ii int, s datetime null )

--insert @a values ( 2, null)
insert @a values ( 3, null)
insert @a values ( 5, null)

update @a
set s =convert(datetime, dbo.Fexample(ii))

select * from @a
```

With the commented line as-is, we get

```
ii          s
----------- -----------------------
3           NULL
5           2012-05-16 00:00:00.000
```

showing that `NULL` is fine as a return value from the function. However, uncomment the `2` line and we get

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

because the year 1750 is before the representable range of `datetime` (which is 1753 to 9999).

Comment: This is definitely the problem, well spotted! The next problem I have is finding the offending value. I have checked distinct values for dates and time, dates are all in 2012 and times are between 00:00:00 and 02:00:00. Is there a problem in Converting `00:00:00 => DATETIME`?

Comment: If you have access to the live data, I don't know of a better way than writing some diagnostic code that cursors through the data, attempting the conversion on each row in turn...

Comment: I have access so I'll run through this now (*googles TSQL CURSOR) :)

Comment: I have checked the data, I will update the question with details.